# How can I create a simple like button thats based on stored user IDs in an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, mongodb

I'm building a like button that displays the number of likes based on the length of an array of user ids and cannot get the user id to save to mongoDB. When I click the button, it increments properly, but does not push the user's id to the array. Is there a way to append the user's id to the "likes" array within the object?

My HTML

```
<button ng-model="object.likes" ng-click="addLike(object)">
    <i class="material-icons">thumb_up</i>
    </br>{{object.likes.length}}
</button>
```

My JS

```
app.controller('likeCtrl', function($http, $location, etc) {
  $scope.addLike = function(object) {
  $http.put('/objects/' + object.id, {
    likes: $scope.currentUser.id
  }).success(function(object) {
    $scope.object.likes.push(object);
  }).error(function(err) {
  return alert(err.message || "an error occurred");
});
}
```

Comment: Authentication of your user should happen server side, not client side. You could change that id manually and potntially fake likes from all your users with a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed "likes: $scope.currentUser.id" to "likes: {$push: $scope.currentUser.id}" and the code worked.

This is a feature of deployd, which I'm using to generate my api.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.object.likes.push(object);` should be `$scope.object.push(object);`
Correct statement will be dependent on the structure of object variable.

Comment: Removing the "likes" from that statement breaks the functionality and it no longer increments. "Likes" is an array property of object. Is there another way to add the user.id to the array?